# __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules in reactive native js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

Good evening dear everyone since yesterday I try to start in react native js to start the development of the mobile version of my site, but when I type the command npm start and I choose the option w I have this error:

[image]

Can you help me? Thank you for all your answers

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'd like to get a web version running so I can run automated tests :)